# This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project,please retry with version 2021.1.1 or newer

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

This is the error shown to me when i try to open my project.

> This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project,please retry with version 2021.1.1 or newer

Comment: Is your version newer than the version number mentioned in the error message?

Comment: If the error mentions that you need to have a specific version... and you don't mention what your version is. How could anyone help you?

Comment: Got this exception when opening android project in Intellij Idea 2022.1 (Build #IU-221.5080.210, built on April 12, 2022). Have no idea how to fix it